# Dropping one band in multi-band raster using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, multi-band, raster-functions

I have two different NAIP imagery rasters, one with five bands and the other with four. I would like to merge the two rasters so they both need to have the same number of bands.

What is the most efficient method to drop one band from a raster in ArcGIS Pro?

I seem to have dropped a band from the second raster, but that was quite a while ago and I can't remember the steps I took.

Comment: "I can't remember the steps I took"... that's why you should write metadata...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use the [Extract Band](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/raster-functions/extract-bands-function.htm) function. In your example:

1. Use your 5 band raster as the input raster
2. Select the 4 bands you want to retain by name or ID
3. Specify the output raster for the extracted bands.

Comment: So in my version of Arcgis pro (2.9) I cannot locate the Extract Band function, and the link to help page doesn't provide the script. I would like to see a snippet of code if anyone has it.

Comment: @user44796, here is the help page for the tool in Pro 2.9. The tool should be there if you search by name in the geoprocessing pane. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/help/analysis/raster-functions/extract-bands-function.htm

Comment: For some reason it isn't available in my help pages. Maybe it will be in 3.0. I just did it in R, as usual.